# Install MAAS on productive system

Tags: server, virtualization, maas, cluster

I'm running 16.04 LTS with 3 VMs.
Got some other servers I might Cluster together with MAAS.

Is it possible to install on the Master productive machine the MAAS and cluster the different servers around to one unique system without erasing existent system and client's content?